# Move a html tag from one html file to another with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have 2 HTML files called **A.html** and **B.html**. Each file has exactly 1  tag. I want to replace the "pre" tag in B.html with the one in A.html with BeautifulSoup but I haven't found any solution so far since the A's has some children.
How do I do that? Thanks!

*A.html*

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    <!-- Some CSS -->
  </style>

  <body>
    <pre>
 <b>Db</b>  <b>Eb</b>  <b>Ab</b>  <b>Gb</b>  <b>F</b>  <b>Bbm</b>  <b>Ebm</b> 
</pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

*B.html*

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    <!-- Some CSS -->
  </style>

  <body>
    <pre>
 
</pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Edit your question to include examples of both files as formatted text.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that.

Comment: Looks like more than one tag in each file. Which particular tag from which file? Do you want to get the `<body>...</body>` from one and replace the same in the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

First let's save the files in variables:

```
htmlA = open("A.html", "r", encoding='utf-8').read()
htmlB = open("B.html", "r", encoding='utf-8').read()
```

Now we will create our soups:

```
soupA = BeautifulSoup(htmlA, 'html.parser')
soupB = BeautifulSoup(htmlB, 'html.parser')
```

Then we can replace the tags:

```
soupB.pre.replace_with(soupA.pre)
```